# Android: bitmapfactory.decodestream returns null

Tags: android, bitmap

I have tried to get the bitmap image from the path of the image. But `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` returns `null` value.

Code:

```
URL url = new URL(path);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
connection.disconnect();
input.close();
```

I have searched in more sites, still i did not get the solution.

Comment: are you sure that the url point to something that BitmapFacotry could decode?

Comment: yes, URL: http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/12f0cc69cd9742faa9c8ee0f7b0d210e.jpg

Comment: there is a bug BitmapFactory.decodeStream(). Instead of decodeStream try save the image on sd, for instance and then load it through BitmpaFoctory or read this: http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Got a Solution :**

```
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create(path) );
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufHttpEntity.getContent());
httpRequest.abort();
```

The problem was that once you've used an `InputStream` from a `HttpUrlConnection`, you can't rewind and use the same `InputStream` again. Therefore you have to create a new `InputStream` for the actual sampling of the image. Otherwise we have to abort the `HTTP` request.

Comment: What's different in this solution to the problem described? In both I see you using the stream only once

Comment: @Guy: Only once we can use inputstream for httprequest, if you are trying to download another image,then it will throw an error as "InputStream already created" like this. so we need to abort the httprequest once downloaded using httpRequest.abort();

Comment: This solution is deprecated today: 22 February 2016

Answer (score 1):

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromUrl(String url)
{
Bitmap bm = null;
InputStream is = null;
BufferedInputStream bis = null;
try 
{
    URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
    conn.connect();
    is = conn.getInputStream();
    bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 8192);
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    if (bis != null) 
    {
        try 
        {
            bis.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (is != null) 
    {
        try 
        {
            is.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
return bm;
}
```

Dont forget to call this within a thread (not Main thread)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but in my case the problem was the resource (image). Be sure the image is not in CMYK color mode since Android does not support CMYK images. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047224/unable-to-load-jpeg-image-with-bitmapfactory-decodefile-returns-null) for more details

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

using the following code iam able to download an image from the url

```
String IMAGE_URL = "http://www.kolkatabirds.com/rainquail8vt.jpg";
            //where we want to download it from
            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(IMAGE_URL);

                //open the connection
                URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

                //buffer the download
                InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is,1024);

                //get the bytes one by one
                int current = 0;

                while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                    baf.append((byte) current);
                }
                //convert it back to an image
                ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(baf.toByteArray());
                Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                img.setImageBitmap(theImage);
```

Comment: ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(1024);

Comment: What is the class ByteArrayBuffer?

Answer (score 0):

**BufferedInputStream  is necessary before decodestream....**

Try this it works perfect for me use;

`BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(inputsteam, 1024);`

Pass buf to decode stream it will work perfectly.

`Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);`

Finally set your bitmap.