# Unable to load JPEG-image with BitmapFactory.decodeFile. Returns null

Tags: android, image, skia

I'm making an app that show a lot of images that are generated from PDF-files by Imagemagick. Some of the images, can't be loaded with BitmapFactory. It simply returns null istead of a bitmap.

The log says:

```
    D/skia(15101): --- decoder->decode returned false
```

It isn't a memory problem as some of the images with the problem is very small, and the images aren't corrupt because I can show them on any other machine. Additionally BitmapFactory is able to decode the width and height if I use

```
    inJustDecodeBounds = true;
```

in the options.

I've tried to load one of the images with an external Image Viewer ([QuickPic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alensw.PicFolder)) without luck. It also returns "Load failed", which indicates that SKIA believes the image is corrupt or at least not supported for some reason.

One of the images that doesn't work can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI8ZH.jpg)

The complete code I use to load it is here

```
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(FILENAME,o);
    int width = o.outWidth;
    int height = o.outHeight;
    /* Width and height decoded successfuly */

    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(FILENAME,o2); 
    /*Bitmap is null */
```

Any idea what is wrong or how it can be circumvented is welcome.

Comment: can u post the code of create the FILENAME?

Comment: FILENAME is simply a constant refering to the specific image-file. In my case it is defined as 'final static String FILENAME = "/sdcard/MPSIT.jpg";'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently [SKIA has a problem](http://code.google.com/p/skia/issues/detail?id=69#c2) with JPG's with a CMYK-profile. The workaround for my problem was to add the parameter "-colorspace RGB" to my imagemagick conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Images with CMYK colorspace, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2w3n.jpg), cannot be decoded by Android by default so they cannot be displayed.

Niels was right, but in case you can't change that parameter on the imageMagick conversion, you can convert the CMYK image to RGB image (supported by Android). There is a library of imageMagick for Android called [android-lib-magick](https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15897163/2232889) is a workaround to this problem.

Just importing [this library](https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick) the code to transform its colorspace is quite simple:

```
ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo(path); // path where the CMYK image is your device
MagickImage imageCMYK = new MagickImage(info);
imageCMYK.transformRgbImage(ColorspaceType.CMYKColorspace);
Bitmap bitmap = MagickBitmap.ToBitmap(imageCMYK);
```

If the image is not in your device or on your SD card, you will need to download it first.

I have implemented two simple methods using [android-lib-magick](https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick) called "getCMYKImageFromPath" and "getCMYKImageFromURL". You can see the code [here](https://github.com/Mariovc/GetCMYKImage):

https://github.com/Mariovc/GetCMYKImage