# Bitmap can't load a 2MB image

Tags: java, android

This is the code I'm using:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;
Bitmap imatgeOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUrl, options);
Bitmap resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imatgeOriginal, 1000, 1000, true);
```

As you can see I resize the image with the Options, but anyways it just crashes on the last line, throwing a NullPointerException. So `imatgeOriginal` is `null`

Why is this happening?

Some notes:

- The image is 2 MB (less than the 16 MB limit) and the size is 1105 × 1491
- The image does exist
- The same code works with images smaller than 1.5 MB

Output in logcat:

```
08-22 15:11:13.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5404): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 15:11:13.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5404):
java.lang.NullPointerException 08-22 15:11:13.249:
E/AndroidRuntime(5404):     at
android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:432) 08-22
15:11:13.249: E/AndroidRuntime(5404):   at
myclass.onAnimationEnd(productView.java:2126) 08-22 15:11:13.249:
E/AndroidRuntime(5404):     at
android.view.animation.AnimationSet.getTransformation(AnimationSet.java:397)
```

Edit:

Something weird is happening, the File Image exists, the route is correct. However android detects this image as CORRUPT or atleast it can't be opened with any tool available (Default gallery, file explorer, no my app).
However, if I download the image to my computer, the image is displayed perfectly. This app is also run in iOS and the same image is actually visible there and looking not corrupt.

So I guess there's some limitations in Android to load JPEG files.

Did you guys have any problem similar like this?

Some resources I've found: 
http://code.google.com/p/skia/issues/detail?id=69#c2
[Unable to load JPEG-image with BitmapFactory.decodeFile. Returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047224/unable-to-load-jpeg-image-with-bitmapfactory-decodefile-returns-null)

Comment: Post the logcat output.

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question shouldnt have done it. There's nothing similar on that question... omg.

Comment: @S.D. Done, check it out. the line 2126 is exactly the last one I've put in this post.

Comment: For some reason, imatgeOriginal is null.  Are you sure your imageUrl is correct and decoding the bitmap correctly?

Comment: In the logcat it should appear a message from the bitmapfactory explaining why it couldn't decode your image.

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán Looks like `imatgeOriginal` is coming null. Which means `decodeFile()` isn't doing its thing, is the image file present, and is it a correct image format ?

Comment: @S.D. as you found out, the problem was the last thing you mentioned. It seems to be corrupt. However decodeFile method didn't show any helpful message. Thanks.

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán That's because native C code is used to decode, native code can only return a value.

Comment: @S.D. I see. However, the issue is not solved. I edit my question to explain what is happening exactly.

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán If you have an image editor on PC, Open it there, and then export it to jpeg/png, copy to android, try to open.

Comment: It works. The issue is that JPEG with CMYK crashes in Android. Check the two links I provided in my question, in my edit exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found out what is happening.

There's an issue with Android and JPEG & CMYK pictures.

You can read more:
http://code.google.com/p/skia/issues/detail?id=69#c2

[Unable to load JPEG-image with BitmapFactory.decodeFile. Returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047224/unable-to-load-jpeg-image-with-bitmapfactory-decodefile-returns-null)

This error is known since 2.0 and there's no workaround at the moment. All you can do is being sure that you won't download any image that have the two properties mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can compress your bitmap size `Bitmap.compress()`

and try this method it'll reduce the size which will maybe help you loading it, because 2MB is huge for some phones

```
int MAX_IMAGE_SIZE = 200 * 1024; // max final file size
Bitmap bmpPic = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath());
if ((bmpPic.getWidth() >= 1024) && (bmpPic.getHeight() >= 1024)) {
    BitmapFactory.Options bmpOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmpOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
    while ((bmpPic.getWidth() >= 1024) && (bmpPic.getHeight() >= 1024)) {
        bmpOptions.inSampleSize++;
        bmpPic = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(), bmpOptions);
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Resize: " + bmpOptions.inSampleSize);
}
int compressQuality = 104; // quality decreasing by 5 every loop. (start from 99)
int streamLength = MAX_IMAGE_SIZE;
while (streamLength >= MAX_IMAGE_SIZE) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bmpStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    compressQuality -= 5;
    Log.d(TAG, "Quality: " + compressQuality);
    bmpPic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compressQuality, bmpStream);
    byte[] bmpPicByteArray = bmpStream.toByteArray();
    streamLength = bmpPicByteArray.length;
    Log.d(TAG, "Size: " + streamLength);
}
try {
    FileOutputStream bmpFile = new FileOutputStream(finalPath);
    bmpPic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compressQuality, bmpFile);
    bmpFile.flush();
    bmpFile.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error on saving file");
}
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you can't compress while loading. First you've to load, then compress. Anyways in my code I am already compressing the image, but it's crashing on loading it.

Comment: Oh, maybe the image is not loading to where it's suppose to x.x