# Android BitmapFactory.decodeFile on jpeg file returns null

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

My app calls the camera to take a picture and save it into my app local directory (`getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()`) which works fine.

When I try to convert the picture into a bitmap using BitmapFactory the result is null. This the code I use :

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;

String picturePath = pictureFile.getAbsolutePath();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);
```

Note that pictureFile was created as follows :

```
pictureFile = File.createTempFile(
                    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                    foodwarnDir      /* directory */
            );
```

Comment: did you check if image is getting save  into app directory?

Comment: `Note that pictureFile was created as follows :` Pretty bad as that will create an empty file (size==0) only.

Comment: @Mohammed : yes my file is created in my app directory.

Comment: @greeapps : this is what is recommended on android developper page developer.android.com/training/camera/…. My code is inspired by it so I guess it is correct

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you forget add permissions READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and/or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ?

```
File locationOfFile = new 
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/images");
File destination= new File(locationOfFile , fileName + ".JPG");
FileInputStream fileInputStream;
fileInputStream= new FileInputStream(destination);
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream);
```

**OR**

This is my working code in my project here:

```
            View imageHolder = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.image_item, null);
            ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView) imageHolder.findViewById(R.id.media_image);

            try {

                String path = uri.getPath();
                Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

                Point p = new Point();
                p.set(100, 100);
                Bitmap bitmapp = waterMark(bmImg, mRefNo, p, Color.RED, 90, 60, true);

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmapp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                Glide.with(this)
                        .load(stream.toByteArray())
                        .asBitmap()
                        .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .into(thumbnail);

                mSelectedImagesContainer.addView(imageHolder);
                thumbnail.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(wdpx, htpx));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Hope this helps you
other helpful [Links1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047224/unable-to-load-jpeg-image-with-bitmapfactory-decodefile-returns-null?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)  [Link2](http://6013029)

Comment: Sorry but for `getFilesDir()` these permissions are not needed.

Comment: I write to my app's private directory ( getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() ) so i guess no permission is required

Answer (score 0):

Create temp file:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp_file, ".jpg", this.getExternalCacheDir());
```

get path created:

```
String mPath = tempFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

now in you activityResult

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
options.inSampleSize = 8;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath, options);
```

Comment: This is what I already do. I added your suggestion of inPreferredConfig in the options but still no improve

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `java.io.File` class. According to Java docs function `.createTempFile` creates empty file on the System.

As such, this file will have only meta info without any content, with zero length, and this is probably a reason why it is not possible to extract Bitmap.

So you need to  Create File Object instance instead of actual file, using `new File()`

You can also use `WeakReference` and similar to Bitmap you create if you're looking to decrease  chance of memory leaks in early implementation.

Comment: this is what is recommended on android developper page https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskScalePhoto. My code is inspired by it so I guess it is correct

Comment: Guide you provided also "puts something" in this newly created file in `dispatchTakePictureIntent()` . Try debugging, by reading `.length` of the file before you extract Bitmap. If it is 0, you have a good chance of finding a problem.

Comment: sorry but I see nothing being put in the newly created file in their code. I debugged as you advised and file length is indeed 0 but why ??

Comment: From guide, `startActivityForResult()` will put picture taken by camera to newly created file, after user takes a picture.

Comment: Nope. I basically don't have to store the picture taken by the camera as I have to OCR it to extract the text. I plan to use the camera API to directly get a bitmap. Is it feasible ?

Comment: Everything is possible, its just a matter of time. But I would say that this is a different question. It seems to me that "Why does it returns null" is answered: the file is empty.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
data.getExtras().get("data");//for getting bitmap
Uri u = intent.getData();// for getting the Uri and get the path from uri
```

for getting data from your camera