# Saving Image Read from Server as Bitmap to Android Internal Storage

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-bitmap, android-internal-storage

I have set up a client-server architecture such that my raspberry pi 3 records audio, performs some analysis on it, and then sends the data (via TCP) to the android app to display on the app screen. The recording and analysis is done and I am able to make the connection and transfer string data that displays on the app with no problem. I am also able to transfer the array of bytes representing the image to the app, but I am trying to figure out how to then display the image on the app.

I am not sure if this is the best approach, but I am attempting to save the image to internal storage and then read from internal storage to an `imageView`.

Explanation for **TCPClient.java**: 
The code that is producing the error is in the run() function of my **TCPClient** class. Like I said before, it successfully reads the array of bytes representing the image from the raspberry pi. As it reads the bytes (1024 bytes at a time), it adds them to a `ByteArrayOutputStream baos`. Once it is done reading all of the bytes, baos is converted to a byte array and stored in data array. Then a `ByteArrayInputStream` is used to read this byte array. Then, from code I found online, I use a `ContextWrapper` and File object as shown. Then I attempt to create a bitmap by using the `decodeStream()` function of `BitmapFactory`. I create a `FileOutputStream` object and then attempt to use bitmap.compress to save the bitmap to android internal storage at the location referenced by the `FileOutputStream`. This last line (                              `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);`
) is throwing a null pointer exception. I am assuming this has something to do with the `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bais);` line but I am not sure how to fix it.

Explanation for **MainActivity.java**:
The `onProgressUpdate` is called when the raspberry pi passes it new data. So, it will be called once the image is saved to internal storage. I haven't been able to test it yet for uploading the image to `ImageView` since I am having errors prior to this point, but I figured I would put it here in case there were any obvious errors I should fix for uploading and displaying the image.

Explanation for python:
The code here opens the image file and reads it as a byte array. It then sends "?start\n" to the android app to let it know an image is being sent as well as the which image (I will be sending two different images). It will then send the size of the byte array (which I determined is actually not the correct number of bytes that are sent to the app) and then the byte array representing the image itself.

**TCPClient.java:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;


public class TcpClient {

    public static final String SERVER_IP = myIPAddress; //your computer IP address

    public static final int SERVER_PORT = myPortNumber;

    // message to send to the server

    private String mServerMessage;

    // sends message received notifications

    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;

    // while this is true, the server will continue running

    private boolean mRun = false;

    // used to send messages

    private PrintWriter mBufferOut;

    // used to read messages from the server

    private BufferedReader mBufferIn;



    /**

     * Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server

     */

    public TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {

        mMessageListener = listener;

    }


    /**

     * Sends the message entered by client to the server

     *

     * @param message text entered by client

     */

    public void sendMessage(String message) {

        if (mBufferOut != null && !mBufferOut.checkError()) {

            mBufferOut.println(message);

            mBufferOut.flush();

        }

    }



    /**

     * Close the connection and release the members

     */

    public void stopClient() {

        Log.i("Debug", "stopClient");

        mRun = false;

        if (mBufferOut != null) {

            mBufferOut.flush();

            mBufferOut.close();

        }

        mMessageListener = null;

        mBufferIn = null;

        mBufferOut = null;

        mServerMessage = null;

    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {

            //here you must put your computer's IP address.

            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server

            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);

            try {

                InputStream sin = socket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream sout = socket.getOutputStream();
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(sin);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


                mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server

                while (mRun) {


                    mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();

                    if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {

                        //Check if data is image
                        if(mServerMessage.equals("?start"))
                        {
                            mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();

                            String fileName = "";

                            if(mServerMessage.equals("signal"))
                            {
                                fileName = "signal.jpeg";
                            }
                            else if(mServerMessage.equals("spec"))
                            {
                                fileName = "spec.jpeg";
                            }

                            // Get length of image byte array
                            int size = Integer.parseInt(mBufferIn.readLine());
                            Log.i("Debug:", "image message size: "+size);


                            // Create buffers
                            byte[] msg_buff = new byte[1024];
                            //byte[] img_buff = new byte[size];
                            int img_offset = 0;

                            while(true){
                                int byte_size = msg_buff.length;
                                int bytes_read = in.read(msg_buff, 0, byte_size);
                                Log.i("Debug:", "image message bytes:" + bytes_read);

                                if(bytes_read == -1){
                                    break;
                                }

                                //copy bytes into img_buff
                                //System.arraycopy(msg_buff, 0, img_buff, img_offset, bytes_read);
                                baos.write(msg_buff, 0, bytes_read);

                                img_offset += bytes_read;

                                Log.i("Debug:", "image message bytes read:"+img_offset);

                                if( img_offset >= size || bytes_read < 1024)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }

                            }

                            try{

                                byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

                                ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

                                ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(ApplicationContextProvider.getContext());
                                File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                File mypath = new File(directory, fileName);

                                //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img_buff, 0, img_buff.length);
                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bais);

                                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

                                //Use compress method on Bitmap object to write image to OutputStream
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

                                fos.flush();
                                fos.close();

                                //Send OK
                                byte[] OK = new byte[] {0x4F, 0x4B};
                                sout.write(OK);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.i("Debug:", "image message" +e);
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                        }

                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class

                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                    }

                }

                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {

                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket

                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.

                socket.close();

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }

    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) must be implemented in the MainActivity

    //class in asynckTask doInBackground

    public interface OnMessageReceived {

        void messageReceived(String message);

    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TcpClient mTcpClient;
    private TextView dbView;
    private TextView roomView;
    private TextView classView;
    private TextView statusView;
    private TextView timeView;
    private ImageView signalView;
    private ImageView specView;
    private Button getAnalysis;
    private Button disconnect;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getAnalysis = findViewById(R.id.get_analysis);
        dbView = findViewById(R.id.db_level);
        roomView = findViewById(R.id.RoomsValues);
        classView = findViewById(R.id.ClassValues);
        timeView = findViewById(R.id.timeStamp);
        signalView = findViewById(R.id.audioPic);
        specView = findViewById(R.id.specPic);
        statusView = findViewById(R.id.status);
        disconnect = findViewById(R.id.disconnect);


        getAnalysis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                statusView.setText("Connecting to Auris...\nRoom analytics will arrive shortly.");
                new ConnectTask().execute("");
            }
        });



        disconnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                mTcpClient.stopClient();
                statusView.setText("Disconnected from Auris.\nReconnect to receive room analysis updates.");

            }
        });



    }

    public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TcpClient> {
        @Override
        protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {
            //we create a TCPClient object and
            mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    publishProgress(message);
                    Log.i("Debug","Input message: " + message);
                }
            });
            //statusView.setText("Get analysis from Auris as it is collected.");
            mTcpClient.run();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            //Store string of values sent from Auris device
            String str = values[0];

            //if data starts with +, then it is the string data
            if(str.startsWith("+"))
            {
                //Split values around spaces
                /*
                    Values in data indices
                        0-8 are room log likelihoods
                        9-12 are class log likelihoods
                        13 is dbA level
                        14 is room model best matched
                        15 is class model best matched

                */
                // Remove +
                str = str.substring(1);
                String data[]= str.split(" ");
                String roomData = "";
                String classData = "";
                String status;

                for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    roomData = roomData.concat(data[i]);
                    roomData = roomData.concat("\n");

                }

                roomView.setText(roomData);

                for(int i = 9; i < 13; i++)
                {
                    classData = classData.concat(data[i]);
                    classData = classData.concat("\n");
                }

                classView.setText(classData);

                dbView.setText(data[13]);
                status = "The room most closely matches " + data[14] + " room model & " + data[15] + " class model.";
                statusView.setText(status);
            }

            else if (str.startsWith("TIME"))
            {
                // Remove "TIME"
                str.substring(4);
                String message = "This room profile represents the room at " + str + ".";
                timeView.setText(message);
            }

            else
            {
                try {
                    String fileName = "";

                    if(str.equals("signal"))
                    {
                        fileName = "signal.jpeg";
                    }
                    else if(str.equals("spec"))
                    {
                        fileName = "spec.jpeg";
                    }

                    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(ApplicationContextProvider.getContext());
                    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    File file = new File(directory, fileName);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                    signalView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            Log.i("onProgressUpdate",values[0]);
        }
    }

}
```

Python Code that sends the image as a byte array:

```
def send_image_to_byte_array(image_file, conn, label):
    with open(image_file, "rb") as imageFile:
        content = imageFile.read()
        conn.sendall("?start\n".encode('utf-8'))
        conn.sendall(label.encode('utf-8'))
        size = len(content)
        strSize = str(size) + "\n"
        conn.sendall(strSize.encode('utf-8'))
        conn.sendall(content)
```

The error happens in this line in **TCPClient.java** run() method:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
```

The exception is:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat,
>   int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

**EDIT:**
I added the python code that sends the byte array of the image as well as the full classes for MainActivity and TCPClient. I also believe that the java code in TCPClient is successfully reading the byte array sent from python because the `in.read(msg_buff, 0, byte_size)` is returning 1024 bytes each time until the last read in which it reads the last remaining bytes and returns a number less than 1024.

Thank you in advance for any and all help! :)

Comment: It looks like that BitmapFactory.decodeStream() does not decode bais to a bitmap. reason might be, from the beginning of the code there are no values coming to the byteArray. Can not directly suggest a solution without a complete look at the code. Still suggest you to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10652532/9292949

Comment: @Anjana Thank you for the reply! I edited it to include the entire .java classes and the python code that sends the byte array! And I think it is getting values from the byteArray since the in.read() function is returning the number of bytes it's reading, unless I'm misunderstanding that function